# Child content inside custom element not being rendered

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom, custom-element

The 'Child content' span shows up in the Light DOM, but isn't actually rendered to the page (see screenshot).

Anyone know why it's not visible? Also I note that it's also apparently not being slotted, which was my attempt to make it visible.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <hello-world>
      <span>Child content</span>
    </hello-world>
    <script>
        var template = `
          <span>Hello world</span>
          <slot></slot>
        `;
        var MyElementProto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
        // Fires when an instance of the element is created
        MyElementProto.createdCallback = function() {
            var shadowRoot = this.createShadowRoot();
            shadowRoot.innerHTML = template;
        };
        document.registerElement('hello-world', { prototype: MyElementProto });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot of DOM tree and page with child not visible]

P.S. This is in Chrome 57.0.2987.133

Comment: I think the element is rendered, but not visible.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that `createShadowRoot` is deprecated. It appears to do what I want and shows no error, but doesn't support slotting (or apparently showing child elements).

Swapping `createShadowRoot()` for `attachShadow({mode: 'open'})` solved the problem.